# C++ What is the standard way of doing cleanup after a exception have been caught?

Tags: c++, exception

So say I have a function that reads from a file. Something goes wrong while reading from the file and I catch an exception. The exception is not fatal; I can simply ask the user to enter a correct file. But in order to ask the user this I might have to exit the function that threw the exception. I was thinking about simply having a `bool` so it returns `true`if all went well or `false` if something went wrong. Is this an accepted way of doing it or is there a standard for how it should be done?

A simple attempt to do it with RAII

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
class FileReader{
    std::ifstream file_descriptor;
public:
    FileReader();
    ~FileReader();
    void readFromFile();
};

FileReader::FileReader() :
        file_descriptor(std::ifstream("test.txt",std::ifstream::in)) {

}

FileReader::~FileReader() {
    file_descriptor.close();
}

void FileReader::readFromFile() {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file_descriptor, line)){ //this can then be in a try block in case file reading goes wrong
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    FileReader fileReader;
    fileReader.readFromFile();
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this what you guys mean? I do however feel I am violating the rule of three/five by having the destructor there. Or will the auto-generated destructor be enough?

Comment: Use RAII. Don't catch the exception too early; only catch where you __have__ to do something.

Comment: This is going to be a matter of opinion.  There is no one way to handle this and exceptions might not be what you even want to use.  Exceptions should be for exceptional circumstances and a bad file name isn't exceptional, users often enter bad information.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm not quite sure how to apply RAII in this instance. Are you saying i should allow the file to be read in an incorrect state and then when i try to use the resource, then i throw the exception?

Comment: RAII may or may not apply directly to the file itself, but any objects created as a result of the parsing of the file should be disposed of correctly on failure and RAII is often the simplest way to handle that.

Comment: _"...Something goes wrong while reading from the file..."_: I read this as meaning that the file had been open successfully but there was a problem reading/parsing its contents (perhaps after a few reads).  The RAII was for the file object and any other resources eg buffers that needed to be cleaned up.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve and the issue you are facing.

Comment: In general, if your constructor code is heavy (e.g. opening a file, parsing, ...), you should consider to not use RAII. Reason: Uncaught exceptions, thrown from a constructor result in ``__exit(-1)`` etc. And if you fail to throw, it gets even worse, you end up with instances in undefined state. In such cases, rethink  your design. Maybe 2 stage initialize (trivial constructor, then ``bool Initialize()``) is the better idea. Typically, classical OOP mind set leads to such problems. Try "C with types" approach instead.

Comment: I agree with other comments: if you must throw exceptions, use RAII. Class constructors establish a class invariant, members maintain it, and the destructor can clean up properly because it can rely on the invariant. That said, I would not use exceptions to report problems with file handling - as error conditions go, problems with file handling are not particularly exceptional or directly fatal and irrecoverable (if they are irrecoverable, it's because of actions of other code, so that other code can use an exception to report a more significant problem even if file errors contribute to that).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the standard way of doing cleanup after a exception have been caught?

The idiomatic way is to do the cleanup in the destructor.

For example, if you open a file, receiving a file descriptor (an integer value), you should do the opening in a constructor, store the descriptor in a member variable, and do the cleanup, including closing the file, in the destructor. This pattern is the RAII idiom.

Comment: I've edited my orignal question with a code example after reading your comment. If you have a minute I would really like your input on it